# How I can remove trailing slash?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router, nuxt-i18n

I use Nuxt.js with [nuxt-i18n](https://github.com/nuxt-community/nuxt-i18n) in **"strategy: 'prefix'"** mode. [About this strategy](https://nuxt-community.github.io/nuxt-i18n/routing.html#strategy).
And I have a problem: 
when I try get the homepage of application, Nuxt redirect me to `localhost:3000/en/`, but I need redirect to `localhost:3000/en`. Without this pernicious trailing slash on the end!

There is snippet of my `nuxt.config.js` file:

```
modules: [
      ['nuxt-i18n',
      {
        locales: ['en', 'es'],
        defaultLocale: 'en',
        strategy: 'prefix',
        vueI18n: {
          fallbackLocale: 'en',
          messages: {
            en: {
              greeting: 'Hello world!'
            },
            en: {
              greeting: '¡Hola mundo!'
            }
          }
        }
      }]
  ]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I have used [@nuxtjs/redirect-module](https://github.com/nuxt-community/redirect-module), and set redirect options `{ from: '/en/', to:'/en' }`. It works.